# Python Question regarding ipaddress.IPv4Network

Tags: python

I was wondering if there was a way to optimize the following that i'm probably missing.

```
ip_list = []
ipv4_list = ipaddress.IPv4Network('1.0.0.0/8')
for i in ipv4_list:
    ip_list.append(str(i)) <-- This takes ~30 seconds
    ip_list.append(i) <-- This takes ~13 seconds
```

I wasn't sure if there was a way to speed this process up.
The only other way i was thinking was break out the /8 into multiple /24s and process those in parallel and do whatever i needed to with them.

Essentially i'm just storing a list of all the ips in a block to do whatever with them. This essentially kills fastapi without increasing the timeout so i just wanted to speed it up.

Comment: The essential part here is "whatever" means. Usually you don't need lists of 16M IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably just a mild speed-up, but using IPNetwork's built-in function `hosts()` will return the same list:

```py
ip_list = list(ipaddress.IPv4Network('1.0.0.0/8').hosts())
```

The fact of the matter is, this is over 16 million addresses and it makes sense it'll perform badly. If you have an alternative way of doing whatever calculation you need that doesn't require iterating over all the subnets it's probably better.